# Bootstrap: Link stays selected after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Code:

```
<h1><a href="#">link</a></h1>
<script>
$("a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U7Y3r/

After the link has been clicked, it keeps a small border:

[image: border]

I have seen this under Firefox and Internet Explorer 10. Does not occur under Chrome or without Bootstrap.

Comment: None of the answers solve the problem! It's nothing about `outline`. It's about the link staying _focused_. After doing `outline: none;` it just removes the outline but the link is still _focused_. If anyone fixes that, please let me know. I'm looking for something similar.

Comment: @weasel http://stackoverflow.com/a/23140002/941764

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's also possible (and probably a bit cleaner) to simply remove the link focus using [$.fn.blur](https://api.jquery.com/blur/):

```
$("a").click(function (e) {
    $(this).blur();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U7Y3r/4/

Answer (score 7):

This is `outline` property, you can set it to `none`:

```
a:focus { outline: none }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Uqzqy/1/

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$("a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).css("outline", "none");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This works fine

```
    $("a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("a").css("text-decoration","none"); 
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U7Y3r/1/

 to get back the same effect, again, http://jsfiddle.net/U7Y3r/2/

Comment: I was specifically targeting this example, this can overridden by selector, I was keen on answering first, so i did not read the question properly, the right answer is [Will.i.am](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15712271/bootstrap-link-stays-selected-after-click/15712357#15712357)'s answer

Answer (score 1):

Actually you *don't* need any javascript. You need to just set "a" on "focus" to "outline: 0;"

```
    /* CSS */
    a: focus { outline: 0; }

    // SCSS
    a {
       &:focus {
          outline: 0;
       }
    }
```

Comment: As an accessibility update. You should indicate focus styles for the end user. You shouldn't remove focus styles OR you should do your own focus styles for the elements.